# CardViewAdapter with multiple nested ViewHolders

Tags: android

I have a question which is more of a practical matter.
I'm creating an app which has multiple Cards - each with different information. I am creating the CardViewAdapter and **inside** I create my ViewHolders for each card. Everything works very well.

My question is - is there a better way of creating the nested classes? Because I have 5 ViewHolders each with 200+ lines of code which makes my CardViewAdapter very hard to read. Is there more practical way of doing that or it is fine like that?

```
public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;

public CardViewAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

private String[] mDataSet;
private int[] mDataSetTypes;

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    View v;
    ViewHolder holder;


    if(viewType == 0){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card1, viewGroup, false);
        return new Card1ViewHolder(v);
    } else if(viewType == 1) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card2, viewGroup, false);
        return new Card2ViewHolder(v);
    } else if(viewType == 2) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card3, viewGroup, false);
        return new Card3ViewHolder(v);
    } else if(viewType == 3) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card4, viewGroup, false);
        return new Card4DialerViewHolder(v);
    } else if(viewType == 4) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card5, viewGroup, false);
        return new Card5SettingsViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    int viewType = 0;

    if(position == 0){
        viewType = 0;
    } else if (position == 1){
        viewType = 1;
    } else if (position == 2){
        viewType = 2;
    } else if (position == 3){
        viewType = 3;
    } else if (position == 4){
        viewType = 4;
    }
    return viewType;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

    }
}

private class Card1ViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    //layout 1
}

private class Card2ViewHolder extends ViewHolder{
    //layout 2
}

private class Card3ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    //layout 3
}

private class Card4ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    //layout 4
}

private class Card5ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    //layout 5
}
```

}

Basically inside the 5 ViewHolders I have completely different layout doing different things.

Comment: Wtf? If u want to use cards with a different content so make one universal `ViewHolder` and `CardItem` that allows you to dynamically set a structure.

Comment: Put more information about all content in cards. I can't write you more without it.

Comment: Or `CardViewAdapter` code.

Comment: I've added the CardViewAdapter - for each Card I have completely different content and layout.

Comment: Sorry, guy, I think I bad explained. I need smth information to I can understand that your card can contains. I.e. an image card, a card with a title, subtitle.

Comment: If u don't want to post a full code of adapter then post cards' xml.

Comment: I have a card with title and content below - spinners, check boxes, radio buttons, sliders. Basically nothing can be set dynamically.

Comment: Okay, then just use a holder with `View` field only (it default in appcompat). Create `CardView` item that contains a type and HashMap with view Ids and values.

Comment: Now, I will explain a full idea like an answer.

Comment: use [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html): this will eliminate different `ViewHolder` types at all - you will have one generic `ViewHolder` counting no more than dozen lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a base class:

```
public abstract class Binder {
    public abstract void bind(View view, Hash<Integer, Object> values);
}
```

So, you can override it for all card views.
The next, declare an item class:

```
public class CardItem {
    public HashMap<Integer, Object> values;
    public int type;
    public Binder binder;
    public bind(View view) {binder.bind(view, values);}
}
```

So, in the data binding you can fill it like `item.bind(holder.view);`.
Use `item.type` to create `ViewHolder` with a correct layout.

Comment: Honestly, your problem has +100500 solutions but the best is a data binding. The Android Studio has the integerated data binding technology as @pskink wrote you and it can generate a similar code automatically. Or it has a data binding library if you use another studio.